# Force less to display a file as text

Tags: less

Sometimes less wrongly recognize file as binary and tries to show hexdump on LHS (usually ones with non-alphanumeric characters but still containing printable ASCII characters). How to force it to recognize it as text?

Comment: Looking for another answer. I have a log file that `cat somefile` shows as ASCII, but `less somefile` says may be binary and displays as such. `echo $LESSOPEN` is empty and `less -L` doesn't help.

Comment: @NathanLong This would probably be acceptable to open a new question on since the solution here does not solve your problem (just make sure to note that). However when you say "may be binary and displays as such", are you saying it display a hex representation of the data, or you see the raw binary data (as all the weird symbols and such)?

Comment: What is LHS? It is new to me.

Comment: @dfc [left-hand side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you have (or your distribution has) a `LESSOPEN` filter set up for `less`.  Try the following to tell `less` to not use the filter:

```
less -L my_binary_file
```

For further exploration, also try `echo $LESSOPEN`.  It probably contains the name of a shell script (`/usr/bin/lesspipe` for me), which you can read through to see what sort of filters there are.  Also try [`man less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less), and read the **Input Preprocessor** section.

Comment: I was using `less` into a script of a service and it wont work until i use `/usr/bin/lesspipe`

Answer (score 4):

For the case of `LESSOPEN` not being the issue. The following `less` options could be tried:

1. `-f` or `--force`:  Besides allowing non-regular files to be opened, it "also suppresses the warning message when a binary file is opened".
2. `-r` or `--raw-control-chars`:
             "Causes raw control characters to be displayed.  The default is to display control characters using the
             caret  notation; for example, a control-A (octal 001) is displayed as `^A`.  Warning: when the `-r` option
             is used, less cannot keep track of the actual appearance of the screen (since this depends  on  how  the
             screen  responds to each type of control character).  Thus, various display problems may result, such as
             long lines being split in the wrong place.
3. `-R` or `--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS`: Weaker form of `-r` above, only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form.  "Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained correctly in most cases." This is useful if you are for example viewing a log file that uses ANSI color control sequences.

You can experiment by pressing keys <kbd>-</kbd> followed by <kbd>r</kbd> without rerunning `less`. You can add these options to `LESS` environment variable to make the setting permanent (e.g. by modifying your shell profile file); if your terminal can show colors I highly recommend adding `-R` in your `LESS` setting. You should make sure your terminal is configured to use the same character encoding as your text file.